# Classification using perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I am a beginner in pattern classification and hence this question may seem trivial. Let's say we are classifying the `IRIS database` of flowers that has 4 features and 3 classes viz `Class1, Class2, Class3` represented as `(0 0 1; 0 1 0; 1 1 0)` respectively. The NN has 3 output neurons. So, when the network outputs, ModelOutput = `1 1 0` we can conclude that the feature belongs to Class3. Now, considering the model mentioned in the paper. The model will have 4 Inputs concepts, and 3 Outputs, one for each class and each of the output concepts are inturn connected by weights. According to the paper [Link](http://www.jofcis.com/publishedpapers/2012_8_10_4007_4016.pdf), the estimated class is the one where the concept value is "highest". So, in this case when the model outputs

```
1 1 0
```

two of the concept values are `1`. So, what is meant by "highest" ? CAn somebody please explain this part? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hard to guess what exactly is used in the paper without studying it in detail (means I can't find the relevant passages). Moreover, by taking a quick look, I'm not sure whether this is the best ressource for this kind of general question. I would rather suggest you to study some book on machine-learning like Bishop or Hastie.

What you're aiming for is multiclass classification. More specifically, you seem to be using the *one-versus-all* strategy, in which you combine the output of a number of binary classifiers (--such one is your perceptron) to form an estimate of the class membership. According to the book "Machine Learning and Pattern Recognition" by Bishop, this can lead to conceptual problems, as in general there exist regions in the input space for which the classification is ambiguous, see the following picture for the case of a perceptron (Fig. 4.2 from Bishop):

[image: The problem of one-vs.-all classifier]

An alternative where this problem doesn't arise is the one-vs.-one classifier, where you train a larger number of binary classifiers.

But to answer your question: usually, the class assignment is rather straightforward. You get a real output `y` of your learner [I guess you are using a multilayer perceptron] which is mapped to [0,1] by the sigmoid function (or more commonly to [-1,1] by the tanh function). Next you need a rule to assign the result 0 and 1 to your output, which is often chosen as `0 if y<0.5` and `1 if y>=0.5`. So, you evaluate your two binary classifications and set up your result vector.

Comment: Thank you. How does one decide on the threshold 0.5 since the classification accuracy seems to depend on it?

Comment: This is a usual choice, but nothing prevets you from using another value. Note that this corresponds to using a different sigmoid function (shifted on the x-axis).

Comment: So, you say that this is the activation function 1/(exp(-lambda*x)) where lambda = 0.5?

Comment: No, I'd say that it is the combination of the two: for example, you can choose the normal sigmoid >0.7 as criterion, or you can find a shifted sigmoid 1/(exp(-(x-beta))+1) > 0.5. Depending on your choice of beta, both may be equivalent.